# What's texture space and screen space in rendering pipeline?

Tags: directx, shader, render, lighting, render-to-texture

can anyone explain the difference of "texture space" and "screen space" When solving advanced Lighting in 3d rendering pipeline? I'm a newbee to shader. thanks in advance！

Comment: <off-topic>Cool, I didn't know Nico was also used in China as a name!!</off-topic>

Comment: Oh,this is my English name.

Comment: That's an odd name to pick. An American working on a project with me once asked me 'Why do they call you Nico?' because he thought it wasn't a real name. :D

Comment: not a real name? so sad.I am not familiar with the naming rules, so I just picked it for convenience. It is hard to pick an English name so that someone can  link your English name to your Chinese name easily.

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but when you are dealing with texture for example if you have a normal map. Each normal you define are coming from a "2d space" like coming towards you. Now in World space your texture is attached to a 3D mesh, each normals have changed depending on the vertex it's being attached. see this good tutorial http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-13-normal-mapping/

Comment: Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, texture space in U, V coordinate system is:
(0.0, 0.0) for bot left, (1.0, 1.0) for top right point of a texture to be sampled.

[image: texture space]

Screen space is the same thing, but it is (-0.5, 0.5) for top left and (0.5, -0.5) for bot right point of render target texture (0 0 is now in center), yet it is transformed by projection matrix, either perspective or orthographical, which makes it, for example, (-400, 300) to (400, -300) for a 2d game with open window 800x600, so you can operate with pixels precisely.

**

Actually in DirectX 11 texture space (0, 0) means top left point of texture

Screen space seems to be (-1, 1) for top left, (1, -1) for bot right.

But the idea is the same.

Comment: Thank you, it is helpful to me.